# How can I allow iptables to properly use a tunnel rather than NAT?

Tags: iptables, nat, site-to-site-vpn

I have two NAT networks connected via a point-to-point tunnel as follows:

```
  | Machine A  |                                         | Machine B  |
  | 1.2.3.4    |<-10.101.3.2-------tun------10.101.3.1-> | 4.5.6.7    |
  | 10.110.0.1 |                                         | 10.100.1.1 |
  -----+--------                                         --------+-----
       |                                                         |
 [ 10.110.1.0/24 net ]                                   [ 10.100.0.0/16 net]
```

Machine A has a public IP on `eth0` and a private IP `10.110.1.1` on `vmbr0`, and is connected over the internet via a p-t-p VPN with Machine B, which has a public IP on `en0` and a private IP on `en1` (and a number of other private networks)

There's clients on both of the LANs using NAT with thw two public IPs. This works fine. (It's done using iptables on Machine A and pfSense on Machine B)

Routing is set up such that Machine A can ping Machine B's private ip `10.100.1.1` *and* can access all hosts on network B `10.100.0.0/16`. Likewise, Machine B (and **all hosts** on network B) can access Machine A, and all hosts on Network A `10.110.1.0/16`

However, hosts on Network A can't establish connections with hosts on network B (E.G. `10.110.1.2` can't ping nor SSH to `10.100.10.50`)

I *suspect* this has something to do with the iptables setup on A, because SSH *from* `10.100.10.50` to `10.110.1.2` works but I can't then SSH in the reverse direction. That says to me that my iptables FILTER rule for `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` works but somehow I suspect that machine A is trying to NAT and use `eth0` for new connections.

I added `ACCEPT destination 10.100.0.0/16` iptables rules everywhere I thought they were need, and then even in places I *didn't* think they were needed when things didn't work, and still can't get outgoing connections from network A to network B working.

How can I properly connect two NAT'ed private networks via a point-to-point tunnel using iptables?

---

Additional info:

iptables on Machine A:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.100.0.0/16       
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:10.110.1.3:80
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:10.110.1.3:443
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client to:10.110.1.4:5222
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5281 to:10.110.1.4:5281
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:64738 to:10.110.1.4:64738
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:64738 to:10.110.1.4:64738
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp multiport dports isakmp,ipsec-nat-t to:10.110.1.10:1194

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.100.0.0/16       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.101.0.0/16       
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.110.1.0/24        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.110.1.0/24        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.110.1.0/24        anywhere
```

Comment: I suspect that Machine B is default gateway for network B, while Network A has another machine for gateway (not Machine A) am I right?

Comment: Should have mentioned that @Anubioz  -- both Machine A and Machine B are the default gateways for their networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, this was a bonehead mistake on my end! Everything on Machine A *was* set up properly, it was actually Machine B's firewall rules blocking this. Machine B had a rule allowing traffic from `10.101.3.2` but was *missing* the rule allowing traffic from `10.110.1.0/24`. Adding that rule corrected the issue.

---

I discovered the problem using `tcpdump` and `nc` as follows:

1. On `10.100.10.50` I executed `nc -kl 60321` to listen for connections on port 60321 (I chose a random port that I knew wasn't used by services we run in order to minimize noise in `tcpdump`)
2. On Machines A and B I executed `tcpdump -s0 -X -i $dev port 60321` where I set `$dev` to either the NAT'ed networks' interfaces (`vmbr0` or `vmx0`) or to the p-t-p interfaces (`tun0`)
3. On `10.110.1.2` I sent data to `10.100.10.50` using: `echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3" | nc 10.100.10.50 60321`
4. I saw the traffic on Machine A's LAN, both Machine A and B's `tun0` interface, but *not* on Machine B's LAN, so that meant the problem was with routing / firewall on Machine B
5. I facepalmed and added the missing firewall rule